# Efficent chisquared test for independence in matlab

Tags: matlab, statistics

I have these bunch of X values and a bunch of Y1,Y2 ,Y3 values. I want to test the independence among X and Y1, X and Y2 and X and Y3. How can I do this efficiently in matlab. My variables are categorical.

I can use crosstab like crosstabl(X,Y1) and get the p values to see the independence/dependence thing. But I have to iterate over Y1, Y2 and Y3 separately this will take lot of time.

I have around 20000 Ys. So is there any way to do this efficiently get 20,000 p values at once in matlab?

```
X Y1
1 0
1 0
2 0
2 1
3 0
3 1
3 1
3 1
```

Comment: In which form do you have your different Ys? If they are columns in a big matrix it wouldn't be a big problem programmatically to do a loop. Are you sure it is that slow? – Internally I don't really see how to effectively vectorize this; for the 20,000 different tests you just need 20,000 different tables, so looping across them is the way to go.

Comment: I just had a look at the code of `crosstabl`, and it appears to me that the *generation* of the table is not too efficiently implemented, it uses a cell array and a loop over the data points, where `accumarray` would be the better choice. So if you do the 20,000 tests and it actually is too slow, this is where I'd try to optimize.

Answer (score 1):

I think to find if the vectors are linearly dependent  or not, you can try to find some coefficients that:

(exmaple)

to find if these vectors are linearly dependent:

[image]

you need to find not-all-zero scalars that:

[image]

in this case:

[image]

and so these vectors are linearly dependent.
you can check this [video](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra/vectors_and_spaces/linear_independence/v/linear-algebra--introduction-to-linear-independence) for more info.

but if you want to know that which of those vectors are more similar, the best way is Analysis of Variance (Covariance).

Analysis of variance (**ANOVA**) is a collection of statistical models used to analyze the differences between group means and their associated procedures (such as "variation" among and between groups). In **ANOVA** setting, the observed variance in a particular variable is partitioned into components attributable to different sources of variation.

**ANOVA** is implemented in MATLAB and can be done for single and multiple factors.

The functions are well documented in MATLAB and you can find them [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/analysis-of-variance-anova-1.html).

To learn it easily you can check [this lesson](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-yQb_ZJnFXw) on youtube.

Comment: My variables are categorical

Comment: What do you mean by that? you can do this ANOVA/ANCOVA analysis for multiple group of objects.

Comment: I mean my variables are not real number. So does variance makes sense for non real number which are just classes. Both my X and Ys are categorical

Comment: then it doesn't make sense. please give an example of your variable in the post to clarify the question.

Comment: I have added some samples

Comment: I don't see how you can use ANOVA to test for independence, no matter what the data structure is. Maybe I'm wrong – but I think you should explicitly explain how to do it to make this a good answer. Otherwise it's more of a pointer.

Comment: NKN, thanks for extending your answer! But I think that you might have misunderstood the question. As far as I understand, the OP wants to test whether two categorical random variables, of which he has sample values, are *statistically independent*. Though these samples have the form of vectors, this is not the same as the question whether two or more vectors are *linearly independent*. To test the former, standard tests are Fisher's exact test or the chi-squared test implemented in `crosstab`.